# React useState to add element to array - instead duplicating array

Tags: reactjs

I'm create a chart that displays random data. I am using useState to store the data array and then update the chart when new updates are pushed. I am using the following code:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([0,1,2,3])
setInterval(function() {
  setData(data => [...data, 3])
  console.log(data)
},5000)
```

However my console.log is outputting multiple arrays like so, which is causing the chart data to jump around:

```
loop0
Array [
  0,
  1,
  2,
  3,
]
*pause*
loop1
Array [
  0,
  1,
  2,
  3,
]
loop0
Array [
  0,
  1,
  2,
  3,
  3,
]
*pause*
loop2
Array [
  0,
  1,
  2,
  3,
]
loop1
Array [
  0,
  1,
  2,
  3,
  3,
]
loop0
Array [
  0,
  1,
  2,
  3,
  3,
  3,
]
loop0
Array [
  0,
  1,
  2,
  3,
  3,
  3,
  3,
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add setInterval logic inside `useEffect` hook. It will only render once. In your case on every setState it renders the whole logic again and again.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const IntervalExample = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([0, 1, 2, 3]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setData((data) => [...data, 1]);
    }, 5000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
        {JSON.stringify(data)}.
    </div>
  );
};

export default IntervalExample;
```

Working example https://codesandbox.io/s/interval-example-m2lk99?file=/src/App.js

Comment: this would be a terrific answer if you spent a little time explaining where the problem is and what your code does to fix it

Comment: My bad instead of using the simple function I am using arrow function just to retain the scope of data state.

Comment: `data` is still in scope in the asker's `function(){...}`, that's not the issue. i'm talking about the whole `useEffect(...)` bit you added :D

Comment: aahh :( ok yeah I am using the useEffect it only renders once and call `setInterval` only one time. Before it was calling multiple times and that was the problem.

Comment: i'm aware but write that in your answer, not here in the comments :D